# Is laravel provide any service to create subdomain dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, subdomain, laravel-5.1

I keenly interested to know is laravel providing their service to create subdomain dynamically ?

Or I should do this by .htaccss, hosts and vhost config files.

Answer (score 1):

Subdomains are not created by frameworks. You need to set them in vhost. You could consider also setting wildcard for your domain and redirect the whole traffic to Laravel but Laravel is not ready to handle multi domains out of the box.